# How to install BCM43228 in ubuntu 17.1,I get some error after make install source code

Tags: 17.10

```
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  AR      /home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/shared/linux_osl.o
symbolmap: 00000001: invalid section
  CC [M]  /home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_pci_probe’:
/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:772:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if ((val & 0x0000ff00) != 0)
  ^~
/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:774:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
   bar1_size = pci_resource_len(pdev, 2);
   ^~~~~~~~~
/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_monitor’:
/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2918:10: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘last_rx’
  skb->dev->last_rx = jiffies;
          ^~
scripts/Makefile.build:316: recipe for target '/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/hadoop/bcm43228_v35_64] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic'
```

Comment: the serious error is error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘last_rx’ skb->dev->last_rx = jiffies;,Please help

Comment: I get the driver from https://www.broadcom.com/support/download-search/?pf=Wireless+LAN+Infrastructure,Linux® STA 64-bit driver

Comment: I have tried so many functions in the internet.

Comment: I have tried so many functions in the internet.
I could show the wifi network info via shell command 'lspci -vv |grep Network'.
Here is some info:
04:00.0 Network controller : Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
Kernel modules: bcma,wl